# Template Log4Net Configuration

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I'm trying to simplify our log4net configuration across a number of projects.

We have multiple services which all create logs. Their appenders are defined in each services app.config. This creates a lot of repetition.

I'd like to shift the log4net configuration out of here and into a Log4NetConfiguration.config file I can link to from each project similar to the accepted answer in this question:

[Share log4net configuration across multiple projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657999/share-log4net-configuration-across-multiple-projects)

This way when developing we only need to change configuration in one place - but users can configure different services log files as they choose.

We call log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() from a common utilities assembly - how do I get this to load the relevant version of Log4NetConfiguration.config from the running service?

Comment: When you add the file as a link, it will be treated like a local file, and will be copied to the bin directory, ready to be loaded in the service: it's prudent to get the path, and pass that to a new instance of `FileInfo`, allowing you to check the file exists before calling `XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fileInfo)` - log4net will not throw exceptions if it cannot find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per StuartD's comment it's in the bin directory.

As such, you can just use Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location to get the location of the config file relevant for the running application.

Then use XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(fileInfo) as suggested.